# Amazon Web Scraper

Tags: web-scraping

Working on this web scraper

```
const express = require("express");
const request = require("request-promise");

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const apiKey = "";
const baseUrl = "http://api.scraperapi.com?api_key=${apiKey}&autoparse=true";

app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Welcome to Scraper API.");
});

//GET Product details
app.get("/products/:productId", async (req, res) => {
  const { productId } = req.params;

  try {
    const response = await request(`enter code here`
      `${baseUrl}&url=https://www.amazon.com/dp/${productId}`
    );

    res.json(JSON.parse(response));
  } catch (error) {
    res.json(error);
  }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log("Server running on port ${PORT}"));
When I run it through the browser choosing a product ID from Amazon
```

I get the following

```json
{
  "name": "StatusCodeError",
  "statusCode": 401,
  "message": "401 - \"Unauthorized request, please make sure your API key is valid.\"",
  "error": "Unauthorized request, please make sure your API key is valid.",
  "options": {
    "uri": "http://api.scraperapi.com?api_key=${apiKey}&autoparse=true&url=https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000EJVYTS",
    "simple": true,
    "resolveWithFullResponse": false,
    "transform2xxOnly": false
  },
  "response": {
    "statusCode": 401,
    "body": "Unauthorized request, please make sure your API key is valid.",
    "headers": {
      "date": "Wed, 22 Jun 2022 23:54:44 GMT",
      "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8",
      "content-length": "61",
      "connection": "close",
      "x-powered-by": "Express",
      "access-control-allow-origin": "undefined",
      "access-control-allow-headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
      "access-control-allow-methods": "HEAD,GET,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS,PUT",
      "access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
      "x-robots-tag": "none",
      "etag": "W/\"3d-jr2uHCCFu/XcPLkZtEYX1XNsziQ\"",
      "vary": "Accept-Encoding"
    },
    "request": {
      "uri": {
        "protocol": "http:",
        "slashes": true,
        "auth": null,
        "host": "api.scraperapi.com",
        "port": 80,
        "hostname": "api.scraperapi.com",
        "hash": null,
        "search": "?api_key=$%7BapiKey%7D&autoparse=true&url=https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000EJVYTS",
        "query": "api_key=$%7BapiKey%7D&autoparse=true&url=https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000EJVYTS",
        "pathname": "/",
        "path": "/?api_key=$%7BapiKey%7D&autoparse=true&url=https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000EJVYTS",
        "href": "http://api.scraperapi.com/?api_key=$%7BapiKey%7D&autoparse=true&url=https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000EJVYTS"
      },
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I went ahead and updated the code which was successful. When I go to upload the app to Heroku I get the following issues

Comment: Example app listening on port 5000
2022-06-25T00:09:03.061665+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2022-06-25T00:09:03.109616+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-06-25T00:09:03.249911+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2022-06-25T00:09:03.321898+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-06-25T00:09:03.331041+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

Comment: I also get a Error code H10

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
const apiKey = "";
const baseUrl = "http://api.scraperapi.com?api_key=${apiKey}&autoparse=true";
```

If you're using an **actual empty string** as your API key, and not just omitting it for this question (yes, you should not show your API key to anyone but the server), then the server is complaining as it should:

> "statusCode":401,"message":"401 - "Unauthorized request, please make
> sure your API key is valid."